# QSqlQuery failing

Tags: sql, qt

```
   bool isOpen = database.open();
  QSqlQuery query(database);
  qDebug("is the database open %d",isOpen);

  bool result = query.exec("SELECT * FROM scales");
```

The database is a global variable which is initiated in another method:

```
database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "first");
database.setDatabaseName("database.db");
bool result = database.open();
```

in both cases the database is opening (returning true) however when I run the query, it returns false. I have run the same SQL in terminal and it works, so there shouldn't be anything wrong with the SQL. So why is the query not executing?

after printing the lastError I got QSqlError(1, "Unable to execute statement", "no such table: scales")

which confuses me as when I check the db with command line it does exist and is spelt correctly. The only thing that I can think of is that it is connecting to a different database file?

Comment: What's the error? (`QSqlQuery::lastError`)

Comment: Where do you create the `scales` table?

Comment: If the database file isn't found, an empty one is created on `open()`.

Comment: Before opening database make sure that file `database.db` exists in your path. You can use `if(QFile::exists("database.db")) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I moved the project and debug folders to a different path and didn't point the IDE to to the new folder so it kept referring back to the old debug folder. Once I pointed it to the correct path it worked fine. It was only when I stated looking at the path suggested by @redmode that I found the error. Cheers all GC